# In the proof of "any projection is associated with a direct sum decomposition"

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is a theorem regarding projections and direct sum decompositions in *Applied Analysis* by Hunter-Nachtergaele:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

The definition of "projection" is given by

> [image]

Here is my **question**:

In the proof of (a), why do we need the "we first show that" part in the beginning of the proof? Wouldn't the argument in the red box be enough?

Comment: They use the first paragraph's result in the very beginning of the red box, so I don't see how the argument in the red box is enough, since it isn't self-contained.

Comment: @Hayden: Where is the first paragraph used in the red box?

Comment: "... then $x=Px$ and ..."

Comment: $x\in ran P$ implies $x=Py$ for some $y\in X$, and it does not necessarily mean $x=Px$

Comment: where the author writes "then $x=Px$"

Comment: They say $x \in$ ran $P \implies x=Px,$ so they use the fact from the outside of the red box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the quick comments, I find that I have just asked a stupid question.

The first paragraph is used in the first sentence of the argument in the red box.